# Excluding some source files from javadoc generation using ANT

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make an Ant Javadoc class exclude two files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060998/how-can-i-make-an-ant-javadoc-class-exclude-two-files)

I want to exclude javadoc generation for some eclipse related files, say `Activator.java` from my ant javadoc target. I have my below sample of code which generates javadoc for different java projects under single document.

```
<project basedir="." default="jdoc" name="ANT_TASK">
<target description="creates the javadoc for the XXXXX module" name="jdoc">
      <javadoc
               destdir="docs/api"
               use="true"
               public="true"
               splitindex="true"
               classpath="..\com.sample.script.modules\bin"
               packagenames="com.sample.package1,
                             com.sample.test1"
               windowtitle="XXXXX 1.0 API"> 
        <sourcepath>
              <pathelement path="..\com.sample.package\src"/>
              <pathelement path="..\com.sample.test\src"/>        
        </sourcepath>
        <doctitle><![CDATA[<h1>XXXXX 1.0 API</h1>]]></doctitle>
        <bottom><![CDATA[<i>Copyright &#169; 1999-2012 XXXX company Ltd. All Rights Reserved.</i>]]></bottom>
      </javadoc>
</target>
</project>
```

Can anyone help me how should I exclude the `Activator.java` file from javadoc generation.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I make an Ant Javadoc class exclude two files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6060998/1164465)

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the javadoc ant task:

> 

```
<fileset dir="src" defaultexcludes="yes">
  <include name="com/dummy/test/**"/>
  <exclude name="com/dummy/test/doc-files/**"/>
</fileset>

<doctitle><![CDATA[<h1>Test</h1>]]></doctitle>
<bottom><![CDATA[<i>Copyright &#169; 2000 Dummy Corp. All Rights Reserved.</i>]]></bottom>
<tag name="todo" scope="all" description="To do:"/>
<group title="Group 1 Packages" packages="com.dummy.test.a*"/>
<group title="Group 2 Packages" packages="com.dummy.test.b*:com.dummy.test.c*"/>
<link offline="true" href="http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/" packagelistLoc="C:\tmp"/>
<link href="http://developer.java.sun.com/developer/products/xml/docs/api/"/>
```

So I would pou the file into the exclude list of the fileset.