# how to exclude files on javadoc ant script

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

[How can I make an Ant Javadoc class exclude two files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060998/how-can-i-make-an-ant-javadoc-class-exclude-two-files)

[Excluding some source files from javadoc generation using ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757587/excluding-some-source-files-from-javadoc-generation-using-ant)

I get the same problem, but i didn't solve it yet... I've tried some of these solutions, but no one worked for me.

my code:

```
<target name="javadocs">
<mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
<fileset dir="${project.dir}\src" defaultexcludes="yes">
  <exclude name=".externalToolBuilders\**"/>
</fileset>
<javadoc 
    excludepackagenames=".externalToolBuilders\**"
    sourcepath="${project.dir}" 
    destdir="${docs.dir}" 
    classpath="${project.dir}" 
    author="true" version="true" 
    use="true" 
    doctitle="&lt;h1&gt;${app.name}&lt;/h1&gt;" />
```

EDIT-1:

after I tried this:

```
<javadoc 
sourcepath="${project.dir}" 
destdir="${docs.dir}" 
classpath="${project.dir}" 
author="true" version="true" 
use="true" >            
<fileset dir="${project.dir}\src" defaultexcludes="yes">
  <include name="**/*.java"/>
  <exclude name=".externalToolBuilders/**"/>
</fileset>
</javadoc>
```

I got this error:

```
javadocs:
[javadoc] Generating Javadoc
[javadoc] Javadoc execution
[javadoc] Loading source file D:\Paul\PaulHostIP\src\AutofitTableColumns.java...
[javadoc] javadoc: error - Illegal package name: ".externalToolBuilders.one-jar-ant-task-0.97.ant.com.simontuffs.onejar.ant"
[javadoc] Loading source file D:\Paul\PaulHostIP\src\CToolTip.java...
[javadoc] javadoc: error - Illegal package name: ".externalToolBuilders.one-jar-ant-task-0.97.test.com.simontuffs.onejar.test"
[javadoc] Loading source file D:\Paul\PaulHostIP\src\HostIP.java...
[javadoc] Loading source file D:\Paul\PaulHostIP\src\Run.java...
[javadoc] Loading source file D:\Paul\PaulHostIP\src\TableColumnSynchronizer.java...
[javadoc] Loading source file D:\Paul\PaulHostIP\src\ThreadDoSomething.java...
[javadoc] Loading source file D:\Paul\PaulHostIP\src\Work.java...
[javadoc] Loading source files for package src...
[javadoc] 2 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in this way:

```
<javadoc 
    destdir="${docs.dir}" 
    author="true" version="true" 
    use="true" 
    doctitle="Test" >
    <fileset dir="${project.dir}/src" defaultexcludes="yes">
         <include name="**/*.java"/>
         <exclude name=".externalToolBuilders/**"/>
    </fileset>
</javadoc>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works a litle bit better, but i still get errors and my "docs" folder is still empty.

Comment: what kind of errors? is it not excluding the package you want to exclude?

Comment: I´m sorry but I can´t post the error message as a comment, that looks terrible, and unfortunately I can´t answer my own question at next 8h, too.

Comment: Hey, thank you a lot!!! This works fine! Which line of the error message tells you, to do it this way? windows is working with "backslashes", why it still works with a "slash" at fileset dir? Further I don´t need a sourcepath!? this is crazy sh*t =)

Comment: You need to read more about javadoc ant task and the associated ones. Glad that helped you, have fun coding :)